# clickable links in revolving banners

Tags: 7, views, blocks

I am a newbie to Drupal 7.21.
I have got as far as creating a rotating banner for my front page.  Now I want to have a clickable link from each banner to a new page that gives more information about each banner topic.  The banners automatically pause nicely when the mouse hovers over them, but I can't find a way to get the link attached to the image.
Can anyone help?
Thanks
Andy

Answer (score 1):

There is a combination of modules listed on the site [HOW TO INSTALL & SETUP VIEWS SLIDESHOW MODULE ON DRUPAL7?](http://www.brightwebsitedesign.com/how-to-install-views-slideshow-module-on-drupal7) that will allow you to do that.

Effectively the modules work together to give you:

- A content type where you can store your banner and the URL
- A view that has some nice JQuery slideshow options for displaying rotating banners that will link to their included URL

Comment: Hello Viral and welcome to Drupal Answers! 
Usually a link-only answer is considered less quality even though the link you've posted is helpful. Kindly add some introduction in your answer itself.

Comment: many thanks viral spiral, that worked for me after a bit of playing around.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a few ways to do this but it really depends on what you want to do.

You can link directly to the node. so if your content node has an image field, simply create a new view and add a new filter to the `fields` section. in the configuration screen, select the `link image to: content` drop down. this should make the image link directly to the node.

the other option is to not have the image link back to the node but another url (can be an internal and external link). for this one, you'll add a content fields filter again. select your image field and in the configure screen, go to the `rewrite results` collapsed section. from there you'll see a check box for `Output this field as a link`. check that and then adjust your link path. you can use a classic url (http:/blah.com/blah) or you can use a replacement pattern.

Comment: thanks austin, i'm slowly learning to play around with the link fields.  Got want i want working anyway.